# HTML/CSS (Bootstrap)- Why isn't my text being centered?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

For some reason, [my text isn't being centered on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8d2s.jpg) even though I have "text-center" class for the caption text. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Evelyn Lauder </h1>
  <h5 class="font-italic"> 1936-2011</h5>
  <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02093/lauder_2093473b.jpg" alt="Evelyn Lauder" /> <br /><br>
</div>
<div style= "width: 50%"; class="text-center font-italic">
  <h7> "Evelyn Lauder was an Austrian American businessman who was well known for popularzing the pink ribbon associated with breast cancer awareness." </h7>
</div>
```

Comment: set width to 100%

Comment: What happens if you delete `"width: 50%"`?

Comment: remove width it should get solved but why do u give width : 50% when your using bootstrap , when there are inbuild classes to do that like col-xs-6 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove the width...

```
<div class="text-center font-italic">
```

or add margin-left if you want the div to be 50% and in the middle...

```
<div style= "width: 50%; margin-left:25%;" class="text-center font-italic">
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpWOod

Answer (score 0):

It is aligning center only. But you have assigned width only 50%. so remove the `width:50%` from your code and it will work.

```
<div class="text-center font-italic">
   <h7> "Evelyn Lauder was an Austrian American businessman who was well known for popularzing the pink ribbon associated with breast cancer awareness." </h7>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove width:50%.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div class="text-center">
  <h1>Evelyn Lauder </h1>
  <h5 class="font-italic"> 1936-2011</h5>
  <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02093/lauder_2093473b.jpg" alt="Evelyn Lauder" /> <br /><br>
</div>
<div class="text-center font-italic">
  <h7> "Evelyn Lauder was an Austrian American businessman who was well known for popularzing the pink ribbon associated with breast cancer awareness." </h7>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way too.
I just added align center to both the div. Then removed the width.

```
<div align="center">
  <h1>Evelyn Lauder </h1>
  <h5><i> 1936-2011</i></h5>
  <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02093/lauder_2093473b.jpg" alt="Evelyn Lauder" /> <br /><br>
</div>
<div align="center">
  <h6><i> "Evelyn Lauder was an Austrian American businessman who was well known for popularzing the pink ribbon associated with breast cancer awareness." </i></h6>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpful.